# Automatic update in JavaScript using PHP code

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to make auto update on my page using JavaScript and php code to read the data from the server

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function timeMsg()
{
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},5000);
}
function myTimer()
{
document.write("<?php 
                session_start();
                $userdata = $_SESSION['views'];
                $name =  $userdata[1]; 
                $mysql_host = 'localhost';
                    $mysql_user = 'root';
                    $connection = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user);
                    mysql_select_db("twitter2", $connection);
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `logindata`";
                    $result =mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo $row['loginname'];
                    }
                        echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
?>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Display alert box in 3 seconds"
onclick="timeMsg()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this code works fine but only display what found in the DB first time 
but if I add more rows in the DB this new rows doesn't appear on the page.

thanks All
 I changed some of my code to be like this

```
        <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function timeMsg()
{
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
}
function myTimer()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","phptest.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Display alert box in 3 seconds"
onclick="timeMsg()" />
<div id="txtHint"></div></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the php file

```
<?php 

                $mysql_host = 'localhost';
                    $mysql_user = 'root';
                    $connection = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user);
                    mysql_select_db("twitter2", $connection);
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `logindata`";
                    $result =mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo $row['loginname'];
                    }

?>
```

and it works fine to me. Thanks for your help

Comment: javascript runs on the client, php runs on the server. what you want is impossible unless you other methods, such as AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript is a client side language.
You cannot print out some php with javascript because it happens in the clients browser.

You need to do it on the server, so I think what you want is an ajax request (XMLHttpRequest) to a server-side php script which look like the content of your document.write.

A very simple and nice cross-browser way doing this is to use jquery.ajax.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

simple tutorial:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/

Answer (score 1):

You doin it wrong - the content of your JavaScript function is interpreted on the server and always the same. Your JavaScript function have to send a request to the Server and handle the response.

If you use JQuery this could look i.e. like this

```
$.get('ajax/script.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

and inside script.php, you could output the database results

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to combine client and server side languages!

Answer (score 0):

steven is right, here is how I would do with jquery:

In javascript:

```
function myTimer()
{
$.ajax({
    url:'path/to/your-script.php',
    type:"POST",
    data:"ajax=true",
    success:callBackMyTimer
});
}

function callBackMyTimer(data)
{
alert(data);
}
```

In your-script.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == 'true')
{
    session_start();
    $userdata = $_SESSION['views'];
    $name =  $userdata[1]; 
    $mysql_host = 'localhost';
    $mysql_user = 'root';
    $connection = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user);
    mysql_select_db("twitter2", $connection);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `logindata`";
    $result =mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['loginname'];
    }
    echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
}
exit;
?>
```